# Make plots of solutions persist

Tags: plotting

How can the code below be modified so that at allow plots of solutions to persist upon clicking in the slope field. For example, after three clicks, the plots of all three solutions should remain. In the current implementation

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{solveEqn, sol},
  solveEqn = 
   Quiet@NDSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] (1 - x[t]/b), x[p[[1]]] == p[[2]]}, 
     x, {t, -10, 10},
     Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "Extrapolation"},
     "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
       "WarningMessage" -> False}];
  sol = x[t] /. solveEqn;

  Show[VectorPlot[{1, a x (1 - x/b)}, {t, -4, 4}, {x, -4, 4}, 
    VectorPoints -> 17, VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
       VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}],

   Plot[Evaluate[sol, {t, -10, 10}], PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]}]]],

 Style["parameters"],
 {{a, 1, "a"}, 0, 4, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 2, "b"}, 1, 10.0, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{p, {0, -2}}, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}]},
    ImageSize -> 8]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very rudimentary implementation of what I think you are asking for.
I also added `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` to the `VectorPlot` to prevent the movement of the plot when clicking.

The idea is to sore the plots in a buffer with a counter telling how many there are. A button is used to clear the buffer.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 Module[{solveEqn, sol, x, t, p1, p2},

  solveEqn = Quiet@NDSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] (1 - x[t]/b), x[p[[1]]] == p[[2]]}, 
     x, {t, -10, 10},
     Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "Extrapolation"}, "ExtrapolationHandler" -> 
     {Indeterminate &, "WarningMessage" -> False}
     ];

  sol = x[t] /. solveEqn;

  p1 = VectorPlot[{1, a x (1 - x/b)}, {t, -4, 4}, {x, -4, 4}, VectorPoints -> 17, 
      VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, VectorStyle -> {{Red, 
      Arrowheads[0]}}, ImagePadding -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"];

  p2 = Plot[Evaluate[sol, {t, -10, 10}], PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.004]},
     ImagePadding -> 1];
  np++;
  AppendTo[store, {p1, p2}];
  Show[store[[1 ;; np]]]],

 Style["parameters"],
 {{a, 1, "a"}, 0, 4, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 2, "b"}, 1, 10.0, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{p, {0, -2}}, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, Locator, 
     Appearance -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 8]},
 Button["clear", {store = {}; np = 0; tick = Not[tick]}, ImageSize -> {80, 40}],
 {{tick, True}, None},
 {{store, {}}, None},(*buffer to save plots*)
 {{np, 0}, None},(*How many in store*)
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, p, tick}
 ]
```

Comment: That's a nice touch. What about my stated question? Can LocatorAutoCreate be used to save new locator points?

Comment: `What about my stated question? Can LocatorAutoCreate be used to save new locator points` sorry, do not see this question here? as I mentioned, it is best to have one specific question for one issue, makes it easier to answer. You can make new question specific for the new issue?

Comment: This question precedes my code above. To explain further,  licking on the slopefield produces a plot of the solution through the locator point. Clicking the mouse at a different location deletes the plot of the first solution and generates a plot of the new solution. I want to keep the plot of the first solution as well. In fact, I want to keep multiple plots.

Comment: @Stephen Ok, I understand now. Yes, you can, you'd need to save all the plots done earlier. You'd need also a button to clear all. I'll add something to do this, but busy at this moment.

Comment: Your code did the trick for me. Now I must figure out how to clear the first plot as well.out